# sketch the region R bounded by the graphs of the equations and find the volume of the solid generated by revolving R about the indicated axis

Tags: calculus

Let $R$ be the region bounded by
$$y=1/x,\quad y=1, \quad y=2,\quad x=0$$
Consider the solid generated by rotating $R$ about the y-axis

Sketch the region, the solid, and a typical disk/washer/shell (your choice)

I know that I have to slice horizontally and integrate with respect to $y$ but I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

I got from $\displaystyle \pi\int_0^1 \frac1y dy$

Am I going about this correctly so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The volume is equal to 
$$\int_{y=1}^2 \pi \frac{1}{y^2}\,dy.$$

**Remark:** You forgot the squaring part: note that a cross-section at height $y$ has area $\pi x^2$, that is, $\frac{\pi}{y^2}$.

In your solution, there is also an issue with the limits of integration. Note that the problem says that the region is bounded in particular by the lines $y=1$ and $y=2$.

The sketch may not be correct, The region of interest is bounded above by the line $y=2$, below by the line $y=1$, on the left by $x=0$ (the $y$=axis) and on the right by $y=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Ahh! Now I see. Alright and from there I take the antiderivative then integrate. So, I got -1/y and I integrated from 2-1 and got the final answer as 1/2pi. Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Yes, that's right, the volume is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.